# jQuery mousemove handler on a masked div

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mask, mousemove, mouseenter

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="one"><div id="element1"></div></div>
<div id="two">some stuff</div>
```

div `one` and `two` are rectangles of same width and height

This is the CSS:

```
#one { position: relative; width: 390px; height: 482px; }
#two { position: relative; z-index: 100; top: -482px; width: 390px; height: 482px; }
```

As you can see div `two` is positioned just over div `one` used as a mask

I need to do something like that:

```
$('#element1').mouseover(function(e){ alert('Hello') });
```

I did that using `mousemove` on div `two` and checking if mouse position was between `x` and `x + width` of `element1` (relative to the parent div `one`) and same thing for `y`.

That solution works but has a problem when I apply `-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);` to `element1`

I'm new and can't post an image but it's easy to understand that the area handled by the `mousemove` on div `two` doesn't correspond with the `element1` div when it is rotated.

How can I know when the mouse moves above `element1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your issue is that div `two` covers the other element, not allowing any events to be registered in the covered elements.

You can fix that by applying CSS `pointer-events:none;` to div `two` to allow events to be registered below the div.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wmdkh/) - Using `pointer-events:none;` on div `two`

---

DEMO uses your exact code as posted with the following additions for visual representation and the rotation:

```
#one{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#element1{
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    height: 5px;
}
```

And the CSS change to `#two`:

```
#two { 
    position: relative; 
    pointer-events:none; 
    z-index: 100; 
    top: -482px; 
    width: 390px; 
    height: 482px; 
}
```

Comment: I added the transform CSS as well for the other browsers so you can test the solution across them. The DEMO works in Chrome (latest), IE9 and FF (latest). The CSS for `pointer-events:none;` also works in IE8 and IE7 Browser Modes but off course rotation doesn't work there.

Comment: Also, this solution only addresses the issue you stated in the post but may not suite as the additional CSS prevents mouse/click events from being registered on div `two`. If you also need those events on div `two` then you might need to separate out `element1` all together and make it the top element by itself or similar.

Comment: pointer-events it's what i need, div two it's just a static mask with no handlers. didn't know that property. thank you dude :)